# python socket difference noted on shell and code in file

Tags: c, sockets, python-2.7, networking

I'm trying to build a python client to interact with my C server. Here's the code for the client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 12209))
print "preparing to send"
s.send("2")
s.send("mmm2.com")
s.send("mypwd")
s.send("5120")
print "Sent data"
root = s.recv(256)
print root
```

When I run this code on the interactive shell (the GUI IDLE) of course line by line, everything runs very fine. But when i save this code in a file and try to run it, it hangs and stops responding according to windows, what's it that I'm just not doing?

Comment: This is not really C related. How do you "*save it a file and try to run it*"?

Comment: well before the hang, it prints out "Sent data", so I guess it hangs at s.recv(), but the server receives nothing

Comment: @Eregrith I write the code in a .py file then run it conventionally

Comment: @BryanKim Does your server respond?

Comment: Nope nothing comes from the server, but if i type the code line by line on the interactive shell, everything works like magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type it line by line, the sent strings are likely received by the server one after another in separate `recv()` calls.

When you execute it in a script, all the `send()` calls run immediately after each other without delay and the server will probably receive all the data in one bulk in a single `recv()` call. So the server will see "2mmm2.commypwd5120", and maybe not handle that correctly. It might wait for more input from the client.

You will need some explicit separation between the values, for example newline characters, so that the server can parse the received data correctly.

Comment: what about a time sleep functionality, could it work? FYI the server is in C

Comment: @BryanKim: It sometimes might work, but its definitely not reliable. There are no guarantees that a sleep would do anything helpful or that the manually typed code will always work. It's just a matter of luck. Using a newline or similar separator is definitely more reliable.

Comment: So what modifications would you make to my client? Coz I'm not so sure about how to incorporate the newline as you suggest

Comment: @BryanKim: `s.send("mmm2.com\n")` would write a newline after the domain, for example. You then have to modify the server to expect this and parse it correctly. First you should make sure that the server really behaves the way I'm assuming.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'm just gonna try it out then I'll tell you how it goes

Comment: Well I tried that but I still had problems on my server's read() 'cause it still kept hanging. But amazingly an all python server-client works amazingly well, but a C server - Python Client has these issues. So I resorted to File I/O tricks to help transfer data from client to server. But that was a great idea